# ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found thrown on windows 8 while opening emulator

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, git-bash

I am having one cordova application made in ionic framework i want to test it in emulator som fired command `ionic emulate android` and it threw following error
Error coming on Git Bash command prompt while running command ionic emulate android.

Error:

```
c:\Users\work\biziHiveMobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: c:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: c:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

Error: c:\Users\work\biziHiveMobile\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat:  Command failed with exit code 1 
at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming \npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

This error is coming on windows 8 PC. I have updated my android SDK to latest version. I have also added emulator accelerator into it from extras of android sdk. STill this error is coming. Anyone knows how to resolve it on windows PC

Comment: Try the steps @Jean Manzo suggests you. I follow his answer and it works like a charm for me !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your terminal try run `android avd`

Create your emulator and try `ionic emulate android` again

Comment: in your command prompt. Otherwise, you can just go to the directory where is located android-sdk and open AVD Manager.

Comment: Type "command prompt" instead of "console" (F12). Also in which directory it must to be run ? What means "Create your emulator" ? Too short explanation. P.S. Actually, your short answer still was guidance enough to fix my problem. Please, edit "console" thing so I can vote +1

Comment: This is what I got after running the command: `************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "avd"
Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk`

Comment: This will work if you're using a version from 2015. As the previous comment states it is now deprecated. You should try download Android Studio and manage your emulators from there.

Comment: 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 12):

Just before running the command `sudo ionic emulate android` go to the Android Studio open the AVD Manager then create AVD(if not yet created) and ***launch it*** in the emulator.
Now execute the command `sudo ionic emulate android` it will run correctly

Comment: click on the `green play button` after creating the `AVD (Android Virtual Device)`.  To start creating an `AVD`, try `CTRL + SHIFT + A` inside `Android Studio` and type `AVD` >> click on the first option...

Answer (score 8):

Update for mac users using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Android Studio for Mac 2.3.3

Context

I got this problem not only in Windows, also in Mac.

This happens when you install the new Android Studio and never created a device and you are trying to run from a terminal. You can get something similar to this:

Example for cordova,

> cordova emulate android

...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.039 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/mtro.josevalerio/WebstormProjects/template/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mtro.josevalerio/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/mtro.josevalerio/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/mtro.josevalerio/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver

Options:

1. You can try to fix it running the commands manually. (hard to do)
2. Starting Android Studio
   Tools > Android > Avd Manager

   - Create Virtual Device
     Pick one device from the list "Nexus 5"
       Click "Download" 
          Wait till the installation finish.
             Pick a name for this devices, "Accept the default"
                Done.
                  You will have at least on device installed

"*Do not forget to check the API version of the device", if you are developing on 23 you can get errors trying to run on a newer device running with 25 and up.*"

Comment: Excellent write up and explanation!

Answer (score 8):

First of all create the emulator image:

Go to tools folder, i.e: "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools"

The command is:

```
android create avd --name thename -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
```

Then emulate:

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

**Make sure to have HAXM accelerator installed: "C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager"

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find the avd manager, go to Help -> Find Action -> avd and click on AVD Manager.

Answer (score 1):

1) In your command promtp write and enter -android avd-

2) Create your emulator

3) Try -ionic emulate android-

Answer (score 1):

1) Follow the instructions on the error message by typing: `"c:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT" avd`

2) Create an AVD. (The AVD manager should pop out)

3) Try ionic emulate android

Answer (score 1):

Download and install android studio, go to tools and then avd manager. For more information you can check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Android Studio and create a virtual machine from there. And run the same command(`ionic emulate android`). Everything should work fine if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your Android Physical Device, then try following things:

1. adb devices - This command should list your connected device. If
   device is not listed, unplugged it and again plug the device. Do not
   forget to put device in Developer mode.
2. Check your Phone, if you got Alert over your phone asking permission, please accept that.
3. Again run the application

Answer (score -4):

To run it on android device connect the device and run `ionic run android`

Comment: The question was regarding emulators.