# No emulator image found while creating a cordova mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I try to emulate cordova mobile app but i get the Error:

> No emulator images (avds) found.

[image]

Even where I create the emulator using android avd still have the same error and when I execute emulator:

-list-avds

I get the list of created avd:

[image]

I'm working on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found thrown on windows 8 while opening emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682523/error-no-emulator-images-avds-found-thrown-on-windows-8-while-opening-emulat)

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).